# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Maybe it's just me being dumb, but I'm sure this should work.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

struct Display
{
  SDL_Window*   window;
  SDL_GLContext context;
};

Display* init()
{
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK , SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

  SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Ice Engine",
                                         800, 600,
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                         SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                         SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );
  if ( !window )
  {
    printf( "%s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    return nullptr;
  }

  SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext( window );

  if ( !context )
  {
    printf( "%s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    return nullptr;
  }

  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  if ( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
    return nullptr;

  return new Display{ window, context };
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Display* display = init();

  bool running = true;
  SDL_Event e;

  while( running )
  {
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) )
      if ( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
        running = false;

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow( display->window );
  }

  delete display;
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

I probably shouldn't be using new and delete and such, but this was just a quick setup to get my project going. The problem is it compiles just fine, but when I run it I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  155
  Current serial number in output stream:  168
```

I've tried without setting the OpenGL context versions, but I just get the same error.

I tried switching to GLFW3 and it all works just fine. It creates me a window and a OpenGL 3.3 core profile context. So it seems to be a problem with SDL2. I'm running ubuntu 15.10 and I installed it via the command line with: `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`.

Comment: try static linking it, if you're not already?   it's like.. /usr/local/bin/sdl-config --static-libs or something

Comment: I ran sdl2-config --static-libs and compiled with the flags it output. Compilation went fine, but I still get the same error.

Comment: very strange.  By the way, it's actually common practice to put that command directly into your build command.. just put backticks around it and it will replace that command with its output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `SDL_CreateWindow` incorrectly. You have mixed up the x, y and width, height settings. The right way would be:

```
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Ice Engine",
                                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                      SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                      800, 
                                      600,
                                      SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );
```

See [SDL_CreateWindow reference](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow). Other than that, your code looks fine.

Comment: I knew I was being dumb. I've done this loads of times before, but It's been a while since the last time. Thanks.